# How to solve a scalar product*unit vector

Tags: vectors

\When I've to multiply a scalar product with a vector how is it done?

My unit vector is: $u=(4,0,-2)$
to make a into a unit vector I got 
$$u=\frac{(4,0,-2)}{\sqrt{4^2+0^2+(-2)^2}}=\frac{(4,0,-2)}{\sqrt{20}}.$$

And the scalar product is $$V\cdot S=6$$

Now I've to evaluate $$(V\cdot S) \times \text{unit vector}(u).$$
How do I do that?

It's from this book page 257 task 17(d):
https://books.google.dk/books?id=53vdMqjQoecC&pg=PA229&hl=da&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

To get product, simply multiply the unit vector with scalar coefficient 6.

$$ 6 u=\frac{6 (4,0,-2)}{\sqrt{20}}=\frac{3 (4,0,-2)}{\sqrt{5}}.$$